# Disconnect a disk correctly

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, array

I want to disconnect a disk from an array; which is the correct process?

1. umount file system
2. remove from volume group
3. **I don't know this step**
4. disconnect physically the disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this disk is used via LVM only then there is no additional step necessary. You can spin the disk down with `hdparm` before disconnecting if you like (may prevent you from disconnecting the wrong one...).

```
hdparm -Y /dev/sdx
```

Comment: can show me a example for spin down the disk

Comment: @rkmax See edit